# How do I quantify the quality of a scan relative to the original?

Tags: color-management, scanning

For example, I imagine [scan quality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scanner#Quality) factors to assess include: color reproduction, scale, optical resolution, etc.

Only real comparison I have for what I'm attempting to understand is how a monitor color correction system allows you to at least know if there's a problem. Though it seems like the only way to know if a scanner was functioning correctly would be to have some sort of "industry" standard sheet to scan and then have read by some analytical software design to evaluate/quantify performance on predefined scanning reproduction factors.

**Any suggests on how to quantify the quality of a scan relative to the original?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at web resources around colour calibration for scanners.   Basically, you need to buy a colorimiter with an accompanying *test target*.

Comment: +1 Awesome, thanks -- here's an [example IT8 test target](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IT8); found based on your use of the word "test target".